# Google not listing my web site

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search

I have a site which is more than 2 months old and it's not showing up when you directly type the URL into Google. Here is the link of site: www.icarda.org

However, the site is listed in Bing and Yahoo without any problem. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have a Google webmasters account for this site?

Answer (score 0):

In Webmaster Tools (http://google.com/webmasters/tools), look for the following things:

1. Can Googlebot access your site? Do a fetch for your robots.txt with Fetch as Google
2. Were there any issues with how Googlebot crawled your site? Take a look in the Crawl Errors section
3. Is there an active site removal in place? Take a look in the Remove URLs feature, specifically looking for Site removals in the "Removed" section.

If you still can't find the reason, please let me know in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply methode... I have checked with your mention items. But they are fine. Is there any other suggetions pls...

Comment: Could you verify in Webmaster Tools both the www and non-www version of your site and check for active removals for both?
Disclosure: I work for Google.

Comment: i found the google bot has not accsess the site by using these sites... http://www.searchenginegenie.com/tools/google-bot-last-accessed-date.php     http://www.webtoolhub.com/tn561397-googlebot-last-access.aspx   Dose it give any means to you methode...!